# Get record from relation - laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables

**ProductAttribute**

```
 - ID (PK) 
 - ProdID (FK) 
 - AttrName
```

**Product**

```
 - ID (PK)
 - ProdName
 - MerchantID(FK)
```

Now I want to fetch all attributes of specific products where merchant id = 5.
Anyone help me to build query in `laravel` eloquent.

I created my self but it shows all attributes from all products with merchant, and shows null to product array where merchant id is not 5.

please help me to solve this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all required `Products` with eagerly loading their attributes like this:

```
$products = Product::where('id', '>', 5)->get()->load('productAttributes');
```

I think the code snippet is self-explanatory. To select only one desired product, you can replace `Product::where('id', '>', 5)` with `Product::find(5)` (or with  `Product::findMany([1, 2, 3])` to get multiple products).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to fetch array of product attribute based on merchant id passed. I have merchant ID and I want to get array of product attributes

Comment: To do that, you can simply `Merchant::find(5)->products()->get()`. In other words, you need to retrieve that merchant first, and then get his products. Calling `products()` for a specific merchant will give you products that are associated with that merchant only.

Comment: where is the products() came from?